How to debug a C# wasm module within a Javascript webapp through VSCode
I am trying to debug a C# application compiled to WASM and embedded in a Javascript application. I need to debug the C# source code from within VSCode. I am not certain this can work because I have not seen anything on the web talk about it but I don't see a technical reason why it would not be possible. Using Visual Studio (not Code) works but I don't know the steps for VS Code.
The use case I want to support is:

User compiles a C# program into web assembly using the wasm-tools workload.
The wasm module is embedded in a Javascript application which uses it for some functionality.
Users can debug the wasm module by attaching a VS Code debugger to the running web app.

Step 3 is the one I am having trouble with. I'm not sure how to connect VS Code to a running instance of the wasm app, I know it uses a websocket to debug but I do know how to connect the IDE to the app.
Using Visual Studio is easier because launching a Debug session will both launch the wasm app as well as hooking the debugger to it. It works out of the box. Though in this example Visual Studio is using its own WasmAppHost process to host the webapp containing the wasm module. However I need to make the procedure work with Visual Studio code since many developers won't use Windows for this project.
So far, I am trying to use C#'s extension in VSCode to load up the solution and start the CS Proj in the same way Visual Studio would.

After starting the Debug instance launches, I get this output:
App url: http://localhost:15213/
App url: https://localhost:17258/
Debug at url: http://localhost:15213/_framework/debug
Debug at url: https://localhost:17258/_framework/debug

After the browser launches, it shows the web page and debugging can proceed. But this only works for cases where the webapp is launched from the IDE, not if it was remotely hosted.
So in recap, is it possible to remote-debug a wasm module embedded in a Javascript environment that is not launched by the IDE ? And if so, how can I connect a VS Code instance to the debug websocket exposed by the wasm module's debug environment ?
Sources:
This page seems to imply this use case is possible, except it does not specifically mention debugging. https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/mono/wasm/features.md#embedding-dotnet-in-existing-javascript-applications
